# Are gets() and puts() technically sound to be used for strings?

Tags: c, string

my question is about

```
gets()
```

and

```
puts()
```

are they a perfect solution for string input and output?

Comment: If by "perfect" you mean "ripe with opportunity for buffer overflows" (`gets`).

Comment: If you want a newline added to your output, `puts()` is fine; if you don't, use `fputs()` instead.  As far as `gets()` is concerned, pretend it never existed.  It cannot be used safely in a hostile environment -- and you should be assuming your programs work in a hostile environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `gets`, see the man page:

> **BUGS**
>
> Never use `gets()`.  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing
>   the data in advance how many characters `gets()` will read, and because `gets()` will continue  to  store
>   characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use.  It has been used to break computer security.  Use `fgets()` instead.

`puts` is fine, if you're just looking to write a string to `stdout`.

Answer (score 6):

`gets` is marked as obsolescent in C99 and has been removed in C11 because of security issues with this function. Don't use it, use `fgets` instead. As an historical note, `gets` was exploited (in fingerd) by the first massive internet worm: the inet worm back in 1988.

`puts` function is OK if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 4):

`gets()` is fundamentally insecure in a really horrific way: it will write an unlimited number of characters to its argument, overflowing any buffer it is provided. As such, it should never, ever be used. Many newer compilers will issue an automatic warning if you use it. Instead, use `fgets()`, which takes a length argument:

```
char buf[...];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
```

On the other hand, `puts()` is totally fine. It's equivalent to `printf("%s\n", x);`, and some compilers will in fact convert certain constant `printf()` calls to `puts()` as a standard optimization. Go wild.